# how can I implement IP in IP protocol (IP encapsulation) in c++?

Tags: sockets, c++11, network-programming, http-tunneling

I want to route my tcp packet from A to B through C.
I am new to network programming and some code samples will be very helpful.

Is there a way to do it through boost library?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I implement IP in IP protocol

### Read the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf). IP is not even mentioned there.

#### So you cannot implement IP in IP in standard hosted C++ code.

However, your device or computer might run some [Linux kernel](https://kernel.org/) (e.g. on [RaspBerryPi](https://raspberrypi.org/)). Then you should read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [ip(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) and [iptables(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables.8.html) and several [Linux HowTO](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HOWTO-INDEX/howtos.html)-s

> Is there a way to do it through boost library?

Did you read the documentation of [boost](https://www.boost.org/)? Did you consider using [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/) libraries ?